# Flask create form with SelectField for every item in a list

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I am new to Flask and i'm trying to make something that requires some skills I am not able to find an answer to when searching SO.

So, the concept is... I have a list of songs that is generated dynamically. Basically we don't know how many there will be. The songs are stored in a list within a list, like this:

```
[[id,artist_name,track_name],[id,artist_name,track_name],[id,artist_name,track_name] etc]
```

I would like to create a form with a SelectField for every list in the list so that the user can give scores to every song in the list.

The route passing on the list item looks like this:

```
@app.route('/submitlist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def submitlist():
    form = forms.Playlist()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate():
            song_data = [[id,artist_name,track_name],[id,artist_name,track_name]...]
            session['thesongs'] = song_data
            return redirect(url_for('songs'))

    return render_template('songs.html', form=form)
```

The route receiving the list looks like this:

```
@app.route('/songs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def songs():
    form = forms.SongsRated()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = form.rating.data
        session['results'] = data
        return redirect(url_for('results'))

    return render_template('songs.html', thesongs=session['thesongs'], form=form)
```

What I am unable to figure out is what the form SongsRated should look like as is should return a dynamic number of SelectFields. I should also be able to collect the return value and identify which SelectField value belongs to which item in the list (thesongs).

And finally I would like to do some verification as I would only like the user be able to score 10 songs (no matter how many) and the scores should all be unique (1-10).

I am sorry if this wasn't explained very well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an explanation of how to create a form dynamically within your view in [this](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/specific_problems/#dynamic-form-composition) tutorial.
Based on that I wrote you the following example.
A form is created with a select field for each item within the list. If the form is submitted, it will provide you with the id and the selected value of the entry for all assigned rankings. The identification is based on the field name, as this contains the original id of the entry.
Double selection is prevented by a [custom validator](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#custom-validators).
In addition, a JavaScript prevents a double selection from happening at all. For this purpose, a listener for change-events is added to each SelectField, which disables the selected ranking for all others or enables it again if a different ranking is selected.

###### Flask (app.py)

```
from flask import (
    Flask,
    render_template,
    request
)
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SelectField
from wtforms.validators import (
    NumberRange, 
    ValidationError
)

LIMIT = 10 # <- HERE!!!

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'your secret here'

def validate_rating(form, field):
    if field.data:
        # Check if a ranking was selected twice.
        for _f in form:
            if _f != field and _f.data == field.data:
                raise ValidationError('A rating can only be given once.')
    else:
        # Check whether the number of ratings corresponds to the number of songs 
        # or the maximum limit (10).
        count,length = 0,0
        for _f in form:
            if _f.name.startswith('track'):
                length += 1
                count += int(not (_f.data == '' or _f.data == 0))
        limit = max([0, min([LIMIT, length])]) 
        if count != limit:
            raise ValidationError(f'You should give up to {limit} ratings.')

class SongsRated(FlaskForm):
    pass

songs = [(i, f'Unknown Artist {i}', f'Untitled Track {i}') for i in range(1,16)]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Generate the actual form.
    class F(SongsRated):
        pass
    for id,artist,track in songs:
        field = SelectField(
            f'{artist} - {track}',
            [
                NumberRange(min=1, max=LIMIT),
                validate_rating
            ],
            choices=list(range(LIMIT + 1)), 
            coerce=int
        )
        setattr(F, f'track-{id}', field)

    # Create an instance of the form.
    form = F(request.form)
    # Once the form has been received and the entry is valid, ...
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # ... inquire about the rankings awarded.
        id_values = [
            (int(f.name[6:]), int(f.data)) for f in form \
            if f.name.startswith('track') and f.data
        ]

    return render_template('index.html', **locals())
```

###### HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post">
      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      {% for field in form -%}
      {% if field.name.startswith('track') -%}
      <div>
        {{ field.label() }}
        {{ field() }}
        {% if field.errors -%}
        <ul>
          {% for error in field.errors -%}
          <li>{{ error }}</li>
          {% endfor -%}
        </ul>
        {% endif -%}
      </div>
      {% endif -%}
      {% endfor -%}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>

    {% if id_values -%}
    <output>{{ id_values }}</output>
    {% endif -%}

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* This script is optional and not strictly required. */

      (() => {
        
        const btn = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]'); 
        const elems = document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="track-"]');
        const temp = Array.from(elems, elem => elem.value);

        const count = temp.filter(val => !(val == '' || val == 0)).length;
        const limit = Math.max(0, Math.min(10, elems.length)); // <- HERE!!!
        btn.disabled = count != limit;

        elems.forEach(elem => {

          // Initialize the previous selection.
          elem.value && (elem.dataset.prev = elem.value);
          Array.from(elem.options).forEach(opt => {
            opt.disabled = opt.value
                && opt.value != elem.value
                && temp.includes(opt.value);
          });

          // Register event listeners.
          elem.addEventListener('change', evt => {
            // Enable and disable based on the selection made.
            const val = evt.target.value
            const prev = evt.target.dataset.prev;
            elems.forEach(sel => {
              if (sel != evt.target) {
                Array.from(sel.options).forEach(opt => {
                  if (opt.value == val && !(val == '' || val == 0)) {
                    opt.disabled = true;
                  } else if (opt.value == prev) {
                    opt.disabled = false;
                  }
                });
              }
            });
            evt.target.dataset.prev = val;

            const cnt = Array.from(elems)
              .filter(elem => !(elem.value == '' || elem.value == 0))
              .length;
            btn.disabled = cnt != limit;

          });
        });

      })()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Can't wait to test this later. Will get back to you. Thank you very much!

Comment: Seems to work just fine, @Detlef. Again, thank you! Now I need to figure out how to validate the form and make sure 10 songs are given a score. Cheers!

Comment: I added additional validators. The format is now limited to an empty string or a number from 0-9. The number of ratings is limited to the number of titles or a maximum of 10. This means that 10 points can still be awarded for a smaller number of titles. If too few ratings are made, the form cannot be sent because the submit button is grayed out. There may be better solutions.

Comment: Thanks again for your work, @Detlef. For some reason, the updated javascript doesn't work how it should (I am able to submit the form no matter how I fill it) and even stranger... it removes the disabled-selections functionality.

Comment: Could there be a conflict beween the wtforms validators and the js validators? As you have explained here, it seems to me that javescript is the best way to validate the form. Love the idea of the disabled submit button and the inactive selection choices.

Comment: The error arose because I used the wrong selector for the submit button within the JavaScript. Sorry, I was playing with the code a bit and it happened. I tried to mark the line for you. Now it should work. I find the JavaScript validator a bit nicer than displaying error messages below the fields. But that doesn't change the fact that validation is also needed on the server side.

Comment: Awesome, now the disabled submit button works!

Comment: if I were to change the allowed input to be able to give a score up to 12... Where in the code will I be able to do this (sorry, I am new to this, it is probably obvious for most people).

Comment: No problem. I marked the points for you. The inability to easily customize the example is one reason why I think there must be a better implementation. If you have any questions or need an explanation, go ahead. The example contains a lot of code.

Comment: Thanks again, it works! The Regexp part was the one I couldn't figure out, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, @Detlef ... Everything is working locally. But when I put this app online there is an issue... Some fields generated from one user will show up when the next user enter a (different) playlist. I was told I should use session to clear it up, but I am unable to do this for the form itself. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I could send you the url if you have the time to check it out. Thank you for all the great help!

Comment: At the moment I have no idea what could cause the problem. Please send me the URL.

Comment: I just realized there is no messaging function on SO. Really don't wanna share the URL on here as it is not really supposed to be a public website. Or maybe I'm unable to access such a system since I am new on here?

Comment: @axl_wolf Unfortunately I have no experience with spotipy. But if I interpret the information correctly, the point is that you should use a uid within a session to make the cache file used by spotipy unique for each user. [This example](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/blob/master/examples/app.py) shows one possibility.